# Prestashop shoppingcart not working

Tags: prestashop, shopping-cart, prestashop-1.5

I'm having some issues with my website and the shoppingcart on in. When I press add to shoppingcart on an item it shows it correctly in the shoppingcart, but when I change page to another item, the shoppingcart is empty again. Anyone know how to solve this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions.

One solution was to disable Varnish Caching on my host.

The other solution was to disable friendly url in the backoffice.

Those two both worked.

Comment: Hi, if you show your varnish config mayby somebody can help you, is posible than your problem is whit cookies.